# I'm not understanding the concept of login/user on Azure

Tags: ssms, azure-sql-database

So as a SQL Server DBA, I can normally create a user, then inside the database U just create a login pointing to that login and then I give the necessary privileges.

I'm trying to understand the concept of logins and users on Azure. Official documentation has some confusing concepts about then and I think I just need to understand the basics to go on.

So, To create a user for a database, do I need to have a Login as we have in a SQL Server instance? I can only find information about AD users.

The original problem I'm having here is that, there's a user inside the database and I just can't change it's Password ( Dev people lost the pass ).

When I use (Inside the database I want to change its passowrd):

```
ALTER LOGIN TheUser WITH PASSWORD = 'SomePassword'
```

SQL Server Management Studio says:

> Msg 5001, Level 16, State 3, Line 139 User must be in the master
>   database.

But there's no user in the master database. how was this user created here without beign created first on master? Do I need a user inside master and then transfer it to the database I want it to access?

[This is not helping me](https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/blog/adding-users-to-your-sql-azure-database/)

EDIT:

So I could connect with a different login ( for some reason im not sysadmin I guess) and I could change the user  password with the command above, but I still would like som esimple explanation about how logins and users works on azure.

Comment: is this Azure SQL database or managed instance. If its the former, have you tried just alter user instead of alter login. I believe azure sql database is more like contained databases, so users will not be associated with logins. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-manage-logins

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because core of the question was due to lack of SA rights and "how does this work" is too broad to stand on its own as a Q&A topic here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple explanation :

A login is an access to a server. It does not necessarily mean access to a database.

When you create a user from a login in a database and grant access (explicit or using a role), the login is able to access a given database/s.

What you are doing is incorrect since you are inside a database and then trying to change the password for a login.

YOu should be in `master` database to change a login's password - provided you have rights to do it.

Comment: Thanks kin. The problem was that I was trying to access the "instance" with a wrong Login. I thought I had sysadmin rights But I didnt. So when I acces the database I could see the user, but on master there was no login. I thought the login was diferent for SQL Server and azure but it's the same. Thanks for you answer.